# Are integrable functions always bounded?

Tags: calculus, integration, definition

So I was going through some questions, and these two made me curious:

1) An integrable function is always bounded

2) If a function is defined on an unbounded interval, then it cannot be integrable.

I looked through the fundamental theorem of calculus, but I just don't seem to understand the connection with the boundaries, open or closed. I did see, however, that the theorem starts with : f is continuous on an interval a,b, which I assume is bounded.

Can somebody please explain if integrable functions can indeed be UNBOUNDED?

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! The function $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$ is defined on $\mathbb R$, but the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$$ exists

Comment: Clearly that function you wrote down is an example of an unbounded function ?

Comment: No, it is defined on an unbound interval, but not unbounded. It is a counterexample for $2)$

Comment: So it is an example of an integrable function which is not bounded?

Comment: No, the function is bounded. To refute $1)$ , you need another function.

Comment: what about the fact that a cotninuous function on a bounded interval has to be bounded? is this true? i assume not, according to the counterxamples

Comment: This is true and not contradicting the counterexamples. The improper integral can exist even if the interval contains a discontinuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Even with the (improper) *Riemann integral*, an integrable function need not be bounded.

*Counter-example*:

The function $f$ defined as $\;f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac1{\sqrt x}&\text{if }\; x>0\\f(0)=&\text{whatever you want} \end{cases}$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ and its integral is
$$\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm d x=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} \int_{\varepsilon}^1\dfrac1{\sqrt x}\,\mathrm d x=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}2\sqrt x\,\biggr|_\varepsilon^1=2.$$

2) The function $\dfrac 1{1+x^2}$ is defined on $\mathbf R$, and integrable on this interval:$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\dfrac {\mathrm d x}{1+x^2}=\arctan x\,\biggr|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}=\frac\pi 2-\Bigl(-\frac\pi2\Bigr)=\pi.$$

Comment: these are two examples of unbounded integrable functions ?

Comment: The second one is an example of an integrable function defined on an unbounded interval, but it is bounded .

Comment: So how should i answer this question : An integrable function is always bounded

Comment: Are you saying that integrable functions always have to be bounded? I am confused

Comment: Okay , maybe i got this. Both questions are false. for the first question , i use 1/square root of x as an example, for the second question i use the second equation you gave me , correct?

Comment: So 1/square root of x is NOT bounded?

Comment: When $x$ tends tro $0$, $\:1/\sqrt x$ tends to $+\infty$ since the denominator gets smaller  and smaller.

Comment: So your examples, really good examples, imply that both questions are false?

Comment: Absolutely. $\,\!$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation . Lastly, sorry to disrupt you , i would make this other assumption : that a continuous function on a bounded interval can also be unbounded... correct?

Comment: More precisely,  a continuous function on a *closed* bounded interval is bounded and attains its bounds (that's Weierstraß' extreme values theorem). On a not necessarily closed, yet bounded interval, any thing can happen.  An example is the tangent function on the bounded open interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: For me, $f:x\mapsto \begin{cases}\frac{1}{\sqrt x}&(0,1]\\ whatever&x=0\end{cases}$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, but the improper integral converges. Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ is not under-bouded, $\sum_{i=0}^{n}(x_{i+1}-x_i)\min_{[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f=-\infty $ for all subdivision $\sigma :0=x_0<...<x_n=1$. And for me, indeed, Riemann integral function are bounded.

Comment: For me, a function is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ if $$\inf\{S^\sigma (f)=\sum_{i=0}^nM_i^\sigma (x_{i+1}-x_i)\mid \sigma :0=x_0<...<x_n=1 \}$$ $$=\sup\{S_\sigma (f)=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} m_i^\sigma (x_{i+1}-x_i)\mid \sigma :0=x_0<...<x_m=1\},$$ where $M_i=\max_{[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f$ and $m_i=\min_{[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f$. In your example, $S_\gamma (f)=-\infty <S^\sigma (f)$. So, I don't think that your example is really an example. What do you think ? but what is your definition of Riemann integrable function ?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that you are talking about the Riemann integral here. If so, yes, the concept is defined only for bounded functions defined on intervals which are closed and bounded, that is, intervals of the type $[a,b]$, with $a<b$.

If $f$ is unbounded or if the interval is unbounded, we get the so-called *improper integrals*. For instance, we sey that $\frac1{x^2}$ is integrable on $[1,+\infty)$, because the limit$$\lim_{M\to\infty}\int_1^M\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2}$$exists and we define$$\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2}=\lim_{M\to\infty}\int_1^M\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2}=1.$$But this is an extension of the concept of Riemann integral.

Comment: Well , the question just asks if an integrable function is always bounded. Doesn't actually state which type of integrable function . Becuase an integrable function can be both improper or riemman , correct?

Comment: @SaraSaletti I strongly suspect that whoever asked the question is expecting an affirmative answer.

Comment: Yes indeed. This is a past exam question, where the answers are : true or false.

Comment: I am confused at this point .

Comment: @SaraSaletti Since this is an exam question, the answer depends upon the way your teacher defined the concept, right?! And it seems that you are the only person around who can determine that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an integrable function can be unbounded.  For example, the function $1/\sqrt{x}$ on the domain (0,1] is unbounded but the integral has a finite value.

Comment: the function 1/x√  is an example of an integrable function which is NOT bounded?

Comment: @SaraSaletti Integrable over the given interval. I am not sure but doesn't "integrable" mean "integrable over $\mathbb R$ ?

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: For me, $f:x\mapsto \begin{cases}\frac{1}{\sqrt x}&(0,1]\\ whatever&x=0\end{cases}$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, but the improper integral converges. Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ is not under-bouded, $\sum_{i=0}^{n}(x_{i+1}-x_i)\min_{[x_i,x_{i+1}]}f=-\infty $ for all subdivision $\sigma :0=x_0<...<x_n=1$. And for me, indeed, Riemann integrable function are bounded.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the definition of the Riemann integrable, and that’s why we define the improper integral without only using the Riemann sum.

Some textbooks use bounded functions in the definition of the Riemann integrable and then the Riemann sum follows, but some textbooks just use the Riemann sum to define. Actually, they are of the equivalence, and we have that if a function is Riemann integrable (without considering the improper integral) if and only if it is bounded.

$$ f \text{ is integrable on a finite closed interval} \iff f \text{ is bounded}.$$

Indeed, in the Riemann sum the term $f(\xi_i)\Delta x_i$ in the neighborhood of the unbounded place is $\infty\Delta x_i=\infty$, could be as large as we like.